# Andengine Loading TMX Files

Tags: android, andengine, tmx

Im having problems loading my tmx level in andengine

```
 TMXLoader mLoader = new TMXLoader(getAssets(), getTextureManager(), 
 TextureOptions.NEAREST, getVertexBufferObjectManager(), 
 new ITMXTilePropertiesListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTMXTileWithPropertiesCreated(TMXTiledMap pTMXTiledMap,
                TMXLayer pTMXLayer, TMXTile pTMXTile,
                TMXProperties<TMXTileProperty> pTMXTileProperties) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    try {
        mTiledMap = mLoader.loadFromAsset("mrsai_demo.tmx");
    } catch (TMXLoadException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

running this gives me a null pointer at this line `mTiledMap = mLoader.loadFromAsset("mrsai_demo.tmx");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out andengine will give u a null pointer if the tile isnt filled in. To fix it just fill in each and every tile on your layer with Tiled.

Comment: hi @user3712476 can i know how to fill tield ? 
do you have any example for this ?
Because i getting same error